# Constraint constant update not work on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout, constraints

I have a strange problem with my constraints on this simple UIViewController.
I have only two elements in it and precisely:

1 UIButton with these constraints:
[image: Button Constraints]
1 PageControl with these constraints:
[image: PageControl Constraints]
The problem is in iOS 8. I have connected the BottomSpace Constraint of UIPageControl to change the constant value (that in iOS 7 works perfectly). In iOS 8 the value doesn't change without any error. My code is simple:

```
pageControlBottomConstraint.constant = 50
```

What is the difference between the two iOS version?

Comment: [pageControl layoutIfNeeded];
Can you try this?

Comment: Yes but nothing change :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following,

**1. call updateConstraintsIfNeeded

2. call layoutIfNeeded (for currentView and ViewYouWantToUpdate)**

So you code should be

```
[pageControl updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[pageControl layoutIfNeeded];
```

if you want to animate the `Constraints`

**Objective-C**

```
[pageControl updateConstraintsIfNeeded]; 
[UIView animateWithDuration:.75f animations:^{
     __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     [pageControl layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
pageControl.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
     weak var weakSelf = self
     weakSelf?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     weakSelf?.pageControl.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```